# REST API design with various creation methods and nested resources

Tags: rest, api-design

There is a resource called `process` that has more than one way to be created, say `create` and `register`.

So I consider these URLs with POST method:

`POST /api/process/create -> returns a process id
POST /api/process/register -> returns a process id`

But a `process` has a nested resource called `item` that may be created. So I consider:

`POST /api/process/{processId}/item -> create a new item
GET /api/process/{processId}/item -> list items`

However this seems very problematic. A processId may be a string with may be "create" and "register".

What is the good approach to design such type of API?

Comment: I'd have a single `POST /api/process` - what differentiates `create` and `register`?

Comment: They have different json payloads. I'd want to map each URL template to a single "json schema".